# Migrating from Adobe Lightroom to Darktable

Tags: photo-management, libraries

Another fed-up Windows user here. Only reason I have stuck with it for so long is because I depend on Lightroom for photo editing. I want to switch to Linux and discovered Darktable. Question: Is there a way to import my existing pictures and the loss-less editing string that goes with each into Darktable? Or will all the edits be lost once I important all my photos into Darktable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The short answer to this is NO, your edits WILL be lost.

The reason for this is that both application does things different ways and our processing differs from each other, making it almost impossible to have 1:1 parameters between Lr and dt processing modules.

However, darktable do support importing standard parts from a xmp sidecar file like rating, color labels and tags / hierarchical keywords.

Answer (score 3):

Since 2013 it is possible to import from Lightroom. Not all functions and editings will be fully imported but most of them. Details about the development you may read on the Darktable Homepage [in this article](https://www.darktable.org/2013/02/importing-lightroom-development/).

So NOT ALL your edits will be lost anymore and MOST OF THEM could be importet. So give it a try, and make sure you made backup before ;-)